# Migrating Exchange 2010 Mailbox to Office 365: Freebusy Data folder corrupt

Tags: exchange-2010, exchange-migration

We have an on-premise Exchange 2010 install which we are migrating to Office 365, and I have a mailbox which is failing to migrate due to "CorruptFolderSecurityDescriptor" errors.  It ended up that some of the folders in the mailbox had permissions entries for users that no longer existed, so I was able to cleanup most of the permissions issues but I still am having problems with a "Freebusy Data" folder.

However, I can not find the "Freebusy Data" folder anywhere so I am unable to fix the permissions on it.  Where can I find the correct path for this folder so I can fix it?

Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Maybe you should take it a look here:

https://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/9549/Recreating-a-missing-free-busy-folder-on-Exchange-2010.html

Here's the whole process of re-creating it if it's missing. and the location of the folder as well.

And Here:

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/lync/en-US/47f865d8-29fc-4edc-9d65-02132244a13d/event-id-14031-unable-to-find-freebusy-public-folder?forum=exchange2010

Comment: While looking through your second link I found a link to the "ExFolders" tool which I was able to use to get a lot more details about user mailboxes, and using it I found the "Freebusy Data" folder and updated the permissions.  Thanks!

Comment: My pleasure Adam, Have a nice day